# Game identification Playstation alien FPS game in urban setting

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I'm trying to find a game I used to play with a friend around ~2008 on a PS2 or PS3.

At first I was almost certain it was in the [XCOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XCOM) universe, but I couldn't find matching screenshots. Here are the details I remember:

- There are multiple (3 or 4 ?) character classes available. We used to play a minigun-wielding one and a laser gun one; I think the latter was supposed to be the medic.
- Missions take place in a modern near-future urban settings: one on a construction site, one in some sort of museum, one in a zoo/park, and one staring in a street where you end up in the subway, I think.

  - Missions involved securing or recovering some stuff while fighting off the aliens in our way.
  - At the beginning of the construction site and the zoo/park missions, we could hear a radio playing a jazzy tune.
- Enemies are mainly some good ol' [Grey aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grey_alien) with different weapons.

  - A major part of them had more of a reptile-like skull and had some light-emitter antenna backpack or something
  - An especially annoying ennemy group had projectile slowly passing through walls in the museum mission.
- There was some sort of "Grey Matter" reward currency you could use to level up your class or unlock new gear.

Comment: Have you asked your friend?

Comment: X-Com Enforcer? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wELU1Lhaczg?

Comment: @Valorum He's right in front of me and don't know either, he vividly remember the jazzy tune though :)

Comment: @Valorum No the game does not look like this and it was first person

Comment: I'm not too confident so comment instead of an answer but [_Area 51_](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rhNCeFtAyCA)?

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot unfortunately not

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found it ! The game is [Resistance 2](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resistance_2) on PS3 !

Here is a video of a coop mission on the Chicago map:

- They start in the street and goes on to the construction yard and into the subway. Also the jazzy tune I was talking about can be heard at 7:34
- We can see the 3 character class : Sharpshooter recording the gameplay, a bunch of laser medic and minigun wielding ones with their force field barriers.
- The Grey aliens ennemies can be seen at the beginning of the video while those I called reptile-like appear later (9:48 for example)
- At the end of the video (13:42), we can see the squad wins "Gray tech"